# Should we always override equals?

Tags: java, inheritance, comparison, equals

When writing one's own classes, is it always necessary to override `equals(Object o)`?

If I don't, will it automatically check that all the fields are the same? Or does it just check if the two variables point to the same object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If one is writing a class that is going to have its objects be compared in some way, then one should override the [`equals`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods.

Not providing an explicit `equals` method will result in inheriting the behavior of the `equals` method from the superclass, and in the case of the superclass being the `Object` class, then it will be the behavior setforth in the Java API Specification for the [`Object`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class.

The general contract for providing an `equals` method can be found in the documentation for the [`Object`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class, specifically, the documentation of the [`equals`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`hashCode`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) methods.

Answer (score 6):

Only override `equals()` if it makes sense. But obviously if you override `equals()` you need to ensure that the `hashcode()` contract isn't broken, meaning if two objects are equal they must have the same hash code.

When does it make sense? When `Object.equals()` is insufficient. That method basically comes down to reference identity, meaning two objects are the same object so:

```
a.equals(b) iff q == b
```

Numbers are an obvious example when it makes sense because `Integer(10)` should equal another `Intger(10)`.

Another example could be when you're representing database records. Let's say you have Student records with a unique integer ID, then it **might** be sufficient implementation of equals to simply compare the ID fields.

Answer (score 5):

The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

To test whether two objects are equal in the sense of equivalency (containing the same information), you must override the equals() method.You should always override the equals() method if the identity operator is not appropriate for your class.

Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Answer (score 2):

While you shouldn't rely on an IDE, Eclipse provides this canned functionality by pressing alt + shift + s and selecting the equals and hashCode menu options.  There is also a toString option.  [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&dq=effective+java&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=5bXSSuaLJ5PIsAPyy8XvCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false) by Josh Bloch has good info on this subject.  The link will take you to the chapter hosted on Google Books that discusses this topic.