# when should I override Equals function?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Always override equals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549553/java-always-override-equals)

should I override `equals` function for any class that I create?

even for very simple classes which only contains some very simple attributes and by **equals**  I need every single attribute of it to be equal?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> ***should I override equals function for any class that I create?***

Override `equals` if (and only if) the object "represents some data", i.e. if it models something such as `Person`, `Car` or `RecipieIngredient` (these typically end up in collections etc). Don't override equals for other types of classes, for example `LoginServlet` or `DatabaseUtil`.

Remember to always override `hashCode` whenever you override `equals`.

> (A natural follow-up question:) ***What happens if I don't override equals and hashCode?***

Any two objects will be considered *unequal* unless they are the exact same object.

> ***[...] I need every single attribute of it to be equal?***

Typically **yes**. It depends on how *you* define your notion of equality. Note that for reference types, you can reuse/delegate to *that* objects implementation of `equals` (and `hashCode`) when implementing your own.

**Related questions:**

- [why we need to override equals and hashcode in java and why cannot we use Object class implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028699/why-we-need-to-override-equals-and-hashcode-in-java-and-why-cannot-we-use-object)
- [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-method-in-java)

Comment: +1 could not have said better, simple but nice explanation.

Answer (score 16):

You should only override `equals()` if you have a reason to do so. As described [here](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html), it is very difficult to write a proper `equals()` method for non-final or mutable classes.

If your application requires some sort of equality concept that is different from "the identical object", then by all means go ahead. Just read the above reference to be aware of what's involved. But as a matter of routine? Definitely not.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the concept of over-riding equals() is more understood if you think it in real-life terms.

Equals method should be over-ridden only when two objects need to be equal logically. Also, if you fear, somewhere in your programme an object may be re-created, then you must over-ride equals().

**A very good example is String objects in java.**

```
   String string1= new String("hello");

   String string2= "hello";
```

Are they equal?.. yes absolutely they are..logically though. You are able to check their equality only because, Java has already over-ridden String equals() method.

As we all know, a class is actually a template for its objects. So let's consider, there is an employee class, which actually determines what attributes employees in the company may hold and actual employees in the company are objects of this class. So typically, attributes of an employee may be as follows.

1.Employee Name

2.Employee ID

3.Date Of Birth
. . . .. . 
. . . . .

So in this case , you should just check whether Employee ID is equal or not in your equals method. But yeah, if your objects lacks such distinct attribute, then you should go ahead and check almost all values to avoid make your programme consider two diffrent people equal.

Comment: +1, nice answer. Regarding your last point though, there are a few gotchas. If an employee is *mutable* the approach of checking some employee id may be risky.

Comment: Well...if something is mutable..they you are totally out of control. The whole equals() world fails.

Comment: what's your reasoning behind that?

Comment: well...you fear that if it is mutable then Employee ID will not be consistent..then ..whatelse could be consistent to ensure equality..