# JAX-RS / JAXB : equals()

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-rs

I'm creating a little webservice with JAX-RS and I cannot access to my GET request http://localhost:8080/MyProject/resources/agenda/{jour}

Here is my code :

```
package com.project.test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "activite")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"but","trancheHoraire", "lieu"})
public class Activite
{
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  @XmlElement(name="nomactivite")
  private String but;
  private TrancheHoraire trancheHoraire;
  private String lieu;
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  public Activite(){

  }

  public Activite(String but,TrancheHoraire trancheHoraire, String lieu)
  {
    this.but = but;
    this.trancheHoraire = trancheHoraire;
    this.lieu = lieu;
  }
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public String         getBut()            { return but; }


  public TrancheHoraire getTrancheHoraire() {
      return trancheHoraire;
  }

  public String getLieu() { return lieu; }

  public void setBut(String but) { 
        this.but = but; 
  } 

  public void setTrancheHoraire(TrancheHoraire trancheHoraire) { 
        this.trancheHoraire = trancheHoraire; 
  } 

  public void setLieu(String lieu) { 
        this.lieu = lieu; 
  } 

  public Date getDate (){

      return this.getTrancheHoraire().getDate();
  }
}
```

TrancheHoraire class :

package com.project.test;

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
//@XmlType(name = "trancheHoraire", propOrder = {"date", "part_journee"})
public class TrancheHoraire
{
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  @XmlElement(required = true)
  private Date date;
//  @XmlElement(required = true)
  private int part_journee;
  public String part_journee_v;
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public TrancheHoraire(){

  }

  public TrancheHoraire(Date date, int part_journee)
  {
    this.date = date;
    this.part_journee = part_journee;

  }



  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public Date getDate() { return date; }

  public int  getpart_journee()
  {
      return part_journee;
  }

  }
```

My Database :

```
package com.project.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ActiviteBD { 

    private static List<Activite> activites = new ArrayList<Activite>(); 

    static { 
        activites.add(new Activite("Réunion", new TrancheHoraire(new Date(01, 10, 2015), 2), "Paris")); 
        activites.add(new Activite("Vacances", new TrancheHoraire(new Date(02, 10, 2015), 2), "Marseille")); 
        activites.add(new Activite("Resto", new TrancheHoraire(new Date(03, 10, 2015), 2), "Lyon")); 
    } 

    public static List<Activite> getActivites() { 
        return activites; 
    }
}
```

And I call webservices with this class :

```
package com.project.test;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 *
 * @author rcaboni
 */
@Path("/agenda")
public class Resource
{


    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public List<Activite> getActivites() { 
        return ActiviteBD.getActivites(); 
    } 


    @GET   
    @Path("{jour}")
    @Produces("application/xml")

      public Activite getActiviteByDate(@PathParam("jour") int jour){  
        System.out.println("getActivite"); 
        Activite tranche = new Activite("Réunion", new TrancheHoraire(new Date(jour, 10, 2015), 2), "Marseille");
        TrancheHoraire th = tranche.getTrancheHoraire();
        System.out.println(tranche.getDate());

        for (Activite _current : ActiviteBD.getActivites()) { 
            System.out.println(_current.getTrancheHoraire());
            if (th.equals(_current.getTrancheHoraire())) {
                System.out.println(_current.getTrancheHoraire());
                return _current;
            } 
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

If I call /agenda, it returns all my activities.
Like this :

[image: XML/GET]

However, if I call /agenda/1   , it should return my first activitie...

In my console : getTrancheHoraire returns something like this : com.project.test.TrancheHoraire@75a630fb

I've read plugin on Equals() class is the only one solution.

Could you help me ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I've read plugin on Equals() class is the only one solution."

I guess "plugin on" means override. If not, then that's you it *should* mean. You need to override it, and describe how the objects will be determined equal. (It should also be noted, when override `equals`, you should also override `hashcode`).

- See [when should I override Equals function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11010626/2587435)

That being said, most IDEs, will be able to generate this for you. For example, with Netbeans, I just right click the class, select "Insert Code" and select `equals() and hashcode()`. Then select the properties I want to include in the comparison. I selected all, and got this

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.date);
    hash = 79 * hash + this.part_journee;
    hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.part_journee_v);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final TrancheHoraire other = (TrancheHoraire) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.date, other.date)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.part_journee != other.part_journee) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.part_journee_v, other.part_journee_v)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I know Eclipse has similar feature.

---

As an aside, your comparison looks kind of odd. Why do you need to create a new `Activite`? The method is `getActiviteByDate`, so why don't you just look for `Activites` with the date.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a / before your {jour} declaration in the @Path annotation, like so:

```
@Path("/{jour}")
```

The mapping you've got currently looks like it may be routing requests to /agenda1.